# Answer wrongly deleted - 4 [resolved]

Tags: discussion, sources-and-citations, answers, moderators

Here is the post:
[According to Hindu scriptures, should one buy a house or rent it?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16349/1049).
This answer is deleted under no clear written policy.

There are 2 requirements for answer to be valid:
1. Attempt to answer (overall SE)
2. Cite sources (Hinduism SE)

My answer satisfies both. It answers all Qn-s in bold & also cites housing related scripture.
Under which written policy is it deleted?

Note: This is Not a duplicate of [Should we change at least one of our current moderators?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/1049). That Qn discusses whether the Mods should be changed. This Qn discusses whether the answer should be deleted.

Comment: -1 for flooding meta, this can be achieved with single post too.

Comment: @Ankit All deleted answers are of different nature & require different discussion. Single post won't help. I am following proper guidelines. `-1 for flooding meta, this can be achieved with single post too` -- So you are now downvoting a user & not a post.

Comment: I am DVing a pattern of posts which are flooding the meta but if you really want to take it personal then I can't help. And yeah I remember I was mod but that has nothing to do with this case.

Comment: `I am DVing a pattern of posts which are flooding the meta` @AnkitSharma, so if you derive some pattern which doesn't resonate with your mindset then you downvote the posts itself, irrespective of contents? As an ex Mod of this site & current mod of movies, you should know that it's called "hate voting". Quite brave enough to admit that. Also interesting that you have decided that 4 new Qn-s have flooded our small meta. :-)

Comment: 1st can you keep "I was mod fact on rest" and be on topic with the current discussion. So now you want to set a environment where if anyone DV you with **proper reasoning**, you will come after them with words like **hate voting** rather then acting mature and understand the constructive criticism.

Comment: **4 new Qn-s have flooded our small meta.**, yeah it did because most of the time I see meta posts here, they are mostly anti-mod and show the community in bad light to outsiders. A single cohesive post is better then  10s of similar meta post flooding the first page

Comment: @iammilind Why are u posting all your questions on the same day? Post one question and once you have finished dealing with it post the next one and so on.  Isn't that the right approach? Right now its too many questions out there. And i am finding it difficult to go through all of them.:)

Comment: @Rickross, these Qn-s were pending for long time. I didn't post to avoid any bad impressions for community. However when Mods said that there is nothing like "target deletion", I thought of this approach. Had I posted daily then some people would have complained, "why are you complaining every now & then. Can't you simply post them all at once?" Also I was unsure of getting answers, hence thought of lightening the burden in 1 shot. Now a mod closed 2 of my Qn-s as dupe & rejected flags. This led me to write a complaint to SO, which I never did so far. Appreciate that the new mod reopened it.

Comment: @iammilind i am not saying that you should post all complaints in one post. That is not possible too. You post all ur complaints under separate Qs but give a time gap between two successive Qs. Post the 2nd Q only when you are completely done with discussing the 1st Q. That's better. Right now proper discussion is not possible coz there are too many Qs to deal with .

Comment: @iammilind And i have already said that this answer should not have been deleted. It should be undeleted ASAP.. I will talk to destroyer reagrding this particular answer.

Comment: @Rickross, Thanks! I understand that. One side advantage of this Blitzkrieg is that, whatever the down voting happened y'day, was removed under "serial voting" policy of SO. Of course it may happen again, but people will be more careful. Actually it's perfectly fine for me if the Qn-s are delayed in answer or not answered at all. Earlier 2 mods might have simply defended the naughty one. :-) But I hope that the new Mod will answer 1 by 1 & will have fruitful discussion. These answers were deleted for long & I too was in limbo. But with recent 1 more deletion, I suddenly felt a need to respond.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16349/according-to-hindu-scriptures-should-one-buy-a-house-or-rent-it#comment48475_16359

Comment: @Pandya, I think you get me wrong :-). If my motive was to undelete this answer by some or the other way then this post would come much before. I don't think any edit is required. First part of answer discusses the main Qn. The 4 points are mainly *swadharma* perspective, which coincide with economy (as the nature of Qn). Based on one's tendencies the actions have to decided. Nothing  harmful in additional info. Since Gita verse is aleady cited, no extra dictation is required as you suggested `Also mention Hindu scripture doesn't mention whether one should buy or rent house.` Answer is valid.

Comment: @iammilind I meant "mentioning that Hindu scripture doesn't mention whether one should buy or rent house" can be considered as an attempt to answer the question. (Whether right or wrong I don't know but I said you to include that to clarify it)

Comment: How is that there's no answer to this question here and yet the answer on the main site is undeleted?

Comment: Related: [What rules does this site currently follow? When does a highly-upvoted post become a rule?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/809)

Comment: @sv. Discussion happened in chat room with many users including mods agreeing for undeletion. The mods are welcome to post an answer for me to accept though.